# Promise in nodejs is not working with error not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I made a promise in `node.js` and try to use it in the controller. But it threw an error that `'not a function'`. And calling promises without a small bracket threw an error `'Can't call then on undefined'`.

Promise code:

```
const Subscription = require("../models/subscription");

exports.pickRandomSubscription = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let pickedSubscription = '';
    Subscription.find({}, function(err, subscriptions) {
        subscriptions.forEach(function(item) {
            pickedSubscription = item;  //get last subscription
        });
        if (pickedSubscription) resolve(pickedSubscription);
        else reject("Subscription not found");
    });
})
```

Calling of promise:

```
const { pickedRandomSubscription } = require("../algo/pickSubscription");
let pickedSubscription = '';
pickedRandomSubscription().then(res => pickedSubscription = res).catch(console.log)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting the promise directly, not a function. You probably wanted to do this:

```
exports.pickRandomSubscription = () => new Promise(function(resolve,reject) { ... }
```

Comment: it didn't work @eol. again same error 'is not a function'.

Comment: Show us how you import `pickRandomSubscription`.

Answer (score 0):

You imported wrong promise name: `pickedRandomSubscription`

```
const { pickedRandomSubscription } = require("../algo/pickSubscription");
```

You should fix it to: `pickRandomSubscription` (not `ed`)

```
const { pickRandomSubscription } = require("../algo/pickSubscription");
```